# POST request not passed

Tags: python, urllib2

I tried to send POST query with this code:

```
def open(self, url, params): 
    self.__opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
    c = self.__opener.open(
        urllib2.Request(
            url,
            urllib.urlencode(params),
            {"User-agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"}
        )
    )

Class.open('http://example.com', {'username': 'test'});
```

But server say to me that username field is empty.

```
urllib.Request('http://example.com?username=test');
```

it works perfectly. How to fix it?

Comment: This isn't Python 3. There is no `urllib2` in Python 3. And, while there is a `urllib`, it's just a package with modules in it, not a module with a class called `Request`. So, first tell us which version you're actually using.

Comment: @abarnert, sorry. I tried to interpret it in Python 2.7.5.

Comment: OK, next problem. In the first version, you're passing `username=test` (www-form-encoded) as the body. In the second version (I'm assuming you actually used `urllib2.Request` there, because there's no such thing as `urllib.Request`?), you're passing it in the query string. While _many_ web services will treat the two as the same thing, there's no requirement that they do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the data in the *request body*; this is perfectly normal in a POST request. However, `http://example.com?username=test` is not a POST request; that's a GET instead.

You can do the same with `urlencode()`; just add it to the URL with `?`:

```
c = self.__opener.open(
    urllib2.Request(
        url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params),
        {"User-agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"}
    )
)
```

Comment: You could also use `urlparse.urlunparse` or a similarly higher-level function instead of string manipulation, which would work if you, e.g., got a URL that already had a query string.

Comment: It's so strangely. Form action param is post. Please, see this repo: https://github.com/Ejz/Common/blob/master/carnage-bot/bot.py (urlopen method)

I think it works, but why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @qwerty: that depends on the server; if the server accepts your GET request but rejects the POST, then stick with GET.